# Generating google map from Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to generate a google map in a web page using latitude and longitude. But map is not shown. SO far i have tried is as follows -

```
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script language=javascript src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
   function initialize(){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatlng, 
             map: map,
         title:"Fast marker"
        });
   } 

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize); 
   $(document).ready(function (){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
         map = new google.maps.Map($('#map'), myOptions);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatlng, 
             map: map,
             title:"Fast marker"
        });
   }                                
</script>
```

How can i generate the map? Could not find any error there. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your code multiple times

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
 function initialize(){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatlng, 
             map: map,
         title:"Fast marker"
        });
   } 

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize); 

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/wexd3spp/1/

CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjZgpw

Comment: Still not working. Could not see any map on your fiddle too.

Comment: It works, you have to unblock the content if the pop up appears,